# How to set the application log in an Azure webapp using Azure resource manager

Tags: json, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

Does anyone know how to set the below diagnostic settings on an Azure Web App using Azure Resource Manager (Powershell or JSON).

[image]

Using .json I can only find these settings

```
     "requestTracingEnabled": true, /* Failed request tracing, aka 'freb' */
     "httpLoggingEnabled": true, /* IIS logs (aka Web server logging) */
     "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 40, /* 40 MB limit for IIS logs */
     "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true, /* Detailed error messages  */
```

Which turns on web server logging to filesystem but NOT Application Logging or to blob storage.

With Powershell this command only seems to work with ASM as it does not find Non-classic storage accounts given to it

```
   Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic
```

Any help would be appreciated.  We are currently using Azure Powershell 0.9.8

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you browse an existing webapp in [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) you'll find a `config/logs` section that looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/.../config/logs",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "North Central US",
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Information",
        "sasUrl": "...",
        "retentionInDays": 14
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

I believe you can use this format in your json template to configure the logging.  (This section would be a sibling to the `config/web` section which contains the settings mentioned in the question.)

Note though that the `config/logs` section is not described in the [System.Web schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json), and so I'd imagine is not currently supported by MS at this time.  I'm pretty sure I've tried it and seen it work though.

Comment: Excellent- Somehow I've never seen the Resource Explorer - should never have to ask a question like this again with this.

Comment: Can anybody help me with how to [retrieve the "sasUrl"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995334/how-to-resolve-sas-url-for-storage-account-in-rm-template?noredirect=1#comment57720111_34995334) in the RM template (json) file, please ?

Comment: The properties `sasUrl` and `retentionInDays` are actually mapped to the AppSetting keys `DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL` and `DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBRETENTIONINDAYS`. So you can set them as regular `SiteConfig.AppSettings` properties.

Comment: @MichaëlHompus Just a cautionary note I thought that meant I could comment them out if they were applied later as app settings but you can't, deployment complains if sasUrl isn't set/present.

Answer (score 6):

The **`Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template json`** section for configuring Application Log (Blob) and Web Server Logging (Storage) based on your screenshot above is as shown below:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "config",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Information",
        "sasUrl": "<Your Azure Blob Storage Account SAS Url>",
        "retentionInDays": null
      }
    },
    "httpLogs": {
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "sasUrl": "<Your Azure Blob Storage Account SAS Url>",
        "retentionInDays": null,
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "failedRequestsTracing": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "detailedErrorMessages": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

References: [AzureWebsitesSamples/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/60f7ffa4aac8f461f47388492c4df76834a8eec2/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json#L109-L135)

Hope this answer your question and help solving your issue.

Please let me know if you need further help or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to set it in the template at the first provision. But it turned out to be easy after resources were provisioned. Please see answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617949/511144 for the actual script to do it that uses `Set-AzureRmResource`