# How to resolve SAS URL for Storage Account in RM Template

Tags: azure, logging, web, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create RM template that creates a web site and configures this for logging into the blob storage.

I saw this [post in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810290/how-to-set-the-application-log-in-an-azure-webapp-using-azure-resource-manager), which shows how to configure this.

The `json` looks somewhat following:

```html
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/.../config/logs",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "North Central US",
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Information",
        "sasUrl": "...",
        "retentionInDays": 14
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

However, I couldn't figure out how the sasUrl should be calculated/resolved into this file?

Comment: I would recommend posting a link to your question on the post you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but I have added the link into this post in the first place. What did I miss? @GauravMantri

Comment: Sorry .... I was not clear ... what I meant was that you go to that question and add a new comment where you add a link to your question. Hopefully the guy who answered that question would see your comment (they would get notification) and chances are that he will answer your question.

Comment: Got it now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moim, I don't think you can create a sasToken within the template.  As MichaelB mentioned you can create it before you do the deployment and either pass it in as a parameter or simply hardcode it in the template (not ideal since this is a secret).  A couple things to add to Michael's code: 1) you need the full URL and a container and 2) you'll want to set an expiry time on the token so it doesn't expire and prevent logging to it.  For example:

```
$SasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Container 'logs'
   -Context $context -Permission rwdl -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(1) -FullUri
```

The other way you can do this is to create a sasToken, store it in Azure KeyVault, and reference that KeyVault secret in the template.  This blog has a few posts that walk through setting that up: http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-refer-an-azure-key-vault-secret-in-an-azure-resource-manager-deployment-template/

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I followed the approach suggested by MichaelB. Although I didn't like it that well, as I wanted to provision the storage account also by the same template. However, doing it before hand via Powershell apparently solves my problem. Thanks for the insights. I will mark MichaelB's reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

To create an SASurl for a container you would use the [New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806416.aspx)

A script like this *should* work

```
 $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $name `
                      -StorageAccountKey ((Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey `
                      -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name).Key1)
  New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name sql 
                                    -Permission rwdl -Context $context
```

You might need to add -FullUri to the end of the last one.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I wanted to do that in RM template (in a Json file).

Comment: If you run that, it will give you the sasUrl for the container, you can then put that into your template file.

Comment: Thank you MichaelB. Cheers.