# Enable logging for an Azure Web App via Powershell or ARM template

Tags: powershell, azure

I've found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810290/how-to-set-the-application-log-in-an-azure-webapp-using-azure-resource-manager/34815694#34815694) that touches on my question, but without any concrete solution and I'm hoping that someone solved this problem:

I'm running a Web App in Azure and we're using v2 storage accounts.  I've determined Powershell that allows logging for a web application to v1 (Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic) but nothing that allows me to log to v2 Storage blobs.

While the UI in the portal allows me to set this up I'm looking for a way to do this through Powershell for purposes of CI and Automated deployment.

----Update re: Set-AzureRMWebApp----

I have also attempted to do this via Powershell using the Set-AzureRMWebApp command.  I may be tripping on syntax, but haven't been able to get this to work either.  I'm familiar with the Resource Explorer, but haven't been able to drop an entry containing something like this into configuration via powershell:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/../config/logs",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "East US",
  "tags": {
    "azenv": "dev",

  },
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureTableStorage": {
        "level": "Off",
        "sasUrl": "MY_SAS_URL"
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Information",
        "sasUrl": "MY_SAS_URL",
        "retentionInDays": 7
      }
    },
    "httpLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "retentionInMb": 35,
        "retentionInDays": null,
        "enabled": false
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "sasUrl": null,
        "retentionInDays": null,
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "failedRequestsTracing": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "detailedErrorMessages": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has successfully done so I would love to see an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the "***Set-AzureRMWebApp***" cmdlet to enable logging with v2 resources.

Check this reference: [Set-AzureRMWebApp on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652487.aspx)

Comment: I have attempted this, but haven't stumbled upon a working command yet.  I'll update my post to mention.

Answer (score 2):

I've configured logging to Blob Storage by adding a SAS URL to Blob Storage using PowerShell. The funny thing is that some settings are stored as AppSettings.
You can use this code to generate a SAS token and configure it in you web app:

```
$sa = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "loremipsumresourcegroup" -Name "loremipsumstore"

New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $sa.Context -Name "webapp-logs" -ErrorAction Ignore

$sasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Context $sa.Context -Name "webapp-logs" -FullUri -Permission rwdl -StartTime (Get-Date).Date -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).Date.AddYears(200)

$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "loremipsumresourcegroup" -Name "LoremIpsumWebApp"

$appSettings = [ordered]@{}
$webapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings | % { $appSettings[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
$appSettings.DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL = [string]$sasToken

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "loremipsumresourcegroup" -Name "LoremIpsumWebApp" -AppSettings $appSettings
```

More explanation about the workings of the code can be found in my [blogpost](https://blog.hompus.nl/2017/05/29/adding-application-logging-blob-to-a-azure-web-app-service-using-powershell/).

Comment: I had to perform 1 additional step.  The token returned by `Get-AzureRmWebApp` includes dates that are Url Encoded.  e.g. `2018-08-29T07%3A00%3A00Z`. `Set-AzureRmWebApp` however expects non-encoded values e.g. 2018-08-29T07:00:00Z.  I had to include `$sasToken = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($sasToken)`