# Is there a way to enable application logging to blob for azure app service using PowerShell or ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

We enable application logging to blob for azure app service in the Azure portal. Is there a way to do this using PowerShell or ARM template. If yes, please provide sample code.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do this using PowerShell or ARM template. If yes, please provide sample code.

We use the powershell command `Set-AzureRmResource -Properties` to do that.

[image]

We also could get the command from `https://resources.azure.com/`. It works correctly on my side.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount   
# get the log setting
$logSetting = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "webAppname/logs" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01  
$logSetting .Properties.applicationLogs.azureBlobStorage.level = "Error" 
$logSetting .Properties.applicationLogs.azureBlobStorage.sasUrl = "storage account sas token url"
$logSetting .Properties.applicationLogs.azureBlobStorage.retentionInDays = 3
# update the log setting
$result = Set-AzureRmResource -Properties $logSetting.Properties -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "webAppname/logs" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force
```

For ARM template, you could refer to this [demo](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/60f7ffa4aac8f461f47388492c4df76834a8eec2/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json#L109-L135).

Comment: Thank you Tom for your reply. Sorry, I won't be able to implement it because of time constraint.