# Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic: specify storage account name?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

How to enable diagnostics for a slot to Azure Table Storage?

I try:

```
> Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic -Name mysite `
     -LogLevel Verbose -Slot myslot -TableStorage `
     -StorageAccountName 'mystorageaccountname'
```

fails:

> ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'mystorageaccountname' was not found.

But it exists.

And when I do:

```
> Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount –ResourceGroupName mygroup `
          –StorageAccountName mystorageaccountname
> Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic -Name mysite `
          -LogLevel Verbose -Slot myslot -TableStorage
```

it fails:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: accountName

whereas [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt788727(v=azure.200).aspx) says:

> -StorageAccountName
>
> Specifies the name of a storage account in which to store logs. The default value is the current storage account.

```
> gcm Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic           5.3.0      azure

> get-module azure*

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     5.3.0      azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureApplicationGatewaySslCertif...
Script     4.3.2      Azure.Storage                       {Disable-AzureStorageDeleteRetentionPolicy, Enable-Azur...
Script     5.3.3      AzureRM.Profile                     {Add-AzureRmEnvironment, Clear-AzureRmContext, Clear-Az...
Script     5.0.0      AzureRM.Storage
```

Update. The same issue for the site.

```
> Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic -Name mysite `
    -LogLevel Verbose -BlobStorage -StorageBlobContainerName appslogs `
    -StorageAccountName 'mystorageaccountname'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the cause of this error. But I've found the similar thread in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2996053d-fcd5-419f-a306-4c44ed8a7dad/enableazurewebsiteapplicationdiagnostic-not-working-when-giving-rm-storage-account?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) which you are experiencing now.

From that **David Ebbo** mentioned like

> The old Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic CmdLet may have
>   issues. Please try something like [this](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/644511d40f379ba4f1ba5ec224d5de29207b6181/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L182-L193) instead. Please look at what
>   the config/log API returns in https://resources.azure.com/ to see
>   everything that you can pass in there.

Comment: Won't help. It says 'created using classic portal' but I'm creating using a template (Resource Manager). Probably to avoid but how then?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to make `Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic` work. And it seems that this Cmdlet can be removed. But `Set-AzureRmResource` was used to set the diagnostic for the site using Azure template. Please see full script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617949/511144